# pst-vehicle: How to attach any object to the truck?

Tags: pstricks

I want to attach a weight vector pointing downward to body of the truck. When I move the truck, the weight vector must also be automatically moved.

[image]

I don't know how to attach it because `\pstVehicle` does not provide us with such an interface. How to attach any object (in this case, a vector) to the truck?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-vehicle}
\psset{unit=4cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
\def\FuncA{0.5*cos(x)+1}
\psplot{0}{4}{\FuncA}
\psVehicle[vehicle=\Truck,showSlope=false]{0.2}{.7}{\FuncA}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-vehicle}
\psset{unit=4cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
\def\FuncA{0.5*cos(x)+1}
\psplot{0}{4}{\FuncA}
\psVehicle[vehicle=\Truck,showSlope=false]{0.2}{0.5}{\FuncA}
\pcline[linestyle=none](!xMTg yMTg)%
      (!xMTg mTgy 0 ge { mTgx } { mTgx neg } ifelse add yMTg mTgy abs add)
\ncput{\rnode{MP}{}}\psdot(MP)
\psline[arrowscale=2]{->}(MP)(!\psGetNodeCenter{MP}MP.x MP.y 1 sub) 
%
\psVehicle[vehicle=\Truck,showSlope=false]{0.2}{2.0}{\FuncA}
\pcline[linestyle=none](!xMTg yMTg)%
    (!xMTg mTgy 0 ge { mTgx } { mTgx neg } ifelse add yMTg mTgy abs add)
\ncput{\rnode{MP}{}}\psdot(MP)
\psline[arrowscale=2]{->}(MP)(!\psGetNodeCenter{MP}MP.x MP.y 1 sub) 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I have uploaded a new version of `pst-vehicle.tex` (The changes should become available on the mirrors of CTAN within the next 24 hours.) that  allows you to use a node with the name `GravC`. See the following example and test the commented-out lines.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-vehicle}
\psset{unit=4cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
%\psset{GravNode=dA12 1}% Vorderradachse aber um 1 nach oben
%\psset{GravNode=0 0}% Hinterradachse
%\psset{GravNode=dA12 2 div 1}% Voreinstellung
\def\FuncA{0.5*cos(x)+1}
\psplot{0}{4}{\FuncA}
\psVehicle[vehicle=\Truck,showSlope=false]{0.2}{0.5}{\FuncA}
\psdot(GravC)
\psline[arrowscale=2]{->}(GravC)([offset=-1]GravC)
%
\psVehicle[vehicle=\Truck,showSlope=false]{0.2}{2.0}{\FuncA}
\psdot(GravC)
\psdot[linecolor=red](GravC)
\psline[arrowscale=2]{->}(GravC)([offset=-1]GravC)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```